# Mean values depending on binning with respect to second variable

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with python / numpy. As input data I have a large number of value pairs `(x,y)`. I basically want to plot `<y>(x)`, i.e., the mean value of `y` for a certain data bin `x`. At the moment I use a plain `for` loop to achieve this, which is terribly slow.

```
# create example data
x = numpy.random.rand(1000)
y = numpy.random.rand(1000)
# set resolution
xbins = 100
# find x bins
H, xedges, yedges = numpy.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xbins,xbins) )
# calculate mean and std of y for each x bin
mean = numpy.zeros(xbins)
std = numpy.zeros(xbins)
for i in numpy.arange(xbins):
    mean[i] = numpy.mean(y[ numpy.logical_and( x>=xedges[i], x<xedges[i+1] ) ])
    std[i]  = numpy.std (y[ numpy.logical_and( x>=xedges[i], x<xedges[i+1] ) ])
```

Is it possible to have a kind of vectorized writing for it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are complicating things unnecessarily. All you need to know is, for every bin in `x`, what are `n`, `sy` and `sy2`, the number of `y` values in that `x` bin, the sum of those `y` values, and the sum of their squares. You can get those as:

```
>>> n, _ = np.histogram(x, bins=xbins)
>>> sy, _ = np.histogram(x, bins=xbins, weights=y)
>>> sy2, _ = np.histogram(x, bins=xbins, weights=y*y)
```

From those:

```
>>> mean = sy / n
>>> std = np.sqrt(sy2/n - mean*mean)
```

Comment: Wow - I did not think of interpreting `y` as "weights" to `x`... Great!

Comment: @JakobS. Nobody does... until seeing it done for the first time!

Comment: @Jaime. You calculate the `std` as `sqrt(x**2-µ**2)`, when it should be `sqrt((x-µ)**2)`, right?

Comment: @Swift Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance#In_terms_of_raw_moments), neither of your formulas is correct without adding some summations somewhere, both can be correct if added in the proper places. I'm pretty confident that the code is conceptually correct.

Comment: @Jaime Thanks! I now understood why yours is the same as in Wikipedia and why it is a very nifty method! Thanks a lot! one more question. Your method uses `sy/N` , where some defintions (like matlabs default) would sometimes use `sy/(N-1)`. Which one would I use for which situations? Thanks!

Comment: With `n-1` you get an unbiased estimator of the population standard deviation based on your data sample. With `n` you get the actual standard deviation of your data sample. This can be a subtle difference... I'd say that more often than not you want the former, but it really depends on what you are doing exactly. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) some reading material, the math is kind of complicated, but you don't really need to understand all of it to get the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
xedges = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), xbins+1)
xedges[0] -= 0.00001
xedges[-1] += 0.000001
c = pd.cut(x, xedges)
g = pd.groupby(pd.Series(y), c.labels)
mean2 = g.mean()
std2 = g.std(0)
```