# Fastest way of calculating mean values for each indices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scipy

I have two 2d arrays of equal shapes: given_array and reference_array. I have to write a file for each unique value of the reference_array computing mean values where the unique value are in the given array.

```
import numpy as np

given_array = np.array([[2,4,5,8,9,11,15],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])

reference_array = np.array([[2,2,2,8,8,8,15],[2,2,2,4,8,8,9]])

unique_value = np.unique(reference_array)

file_out = open('file_out', 'w')

for unique in unique_value:
    index = reference_array == unique
    mean = np.mean(given_array[index])
    file_out.write(str(unique) + ',' + str(mean) + '\n')

file_out.close()
```

The above code works, but in my real problem two arrays are extremely large as read from raster image, and it is taking few days to complete the processing.

Would be grateful if someone could provide fastest way of producing the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going only once through the arrays might be faster, even it uses pure python:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip

add = lambda (sum_, count), value: (sum_+value, count+1)
unique = defaultdict(lambda:(0,0))
for ref, value in izip(reference_array.flat, given_array.flat):
    unique[ref] = add(unique[ref], float(value))

with open('file.out', 'w') as out:
    for ref, (sum_, count) in unique.iteritems():
        out.write('%f,%f\n' % (ref, sum_ / count))
```

In contrast to the solution of the OP, finding the unique values and calculating the mean values is done in one loop. `unique` is a dictionary where the key is one reference value and the value is a pair of the sum and count of all the given values which have the same reference value. After the loop, not only all unique reference values are put into the dictionary `unique` but also all given elements are sorted to their reference value as sum and count, which can easily used to calculate the mean value in a second step.

The complexity of the problem was reduced from `size_of_array * number_of_unique_values` to `size_of_array + number_of_unique_values`.

Comment: thanks, upvoted, will test soon. but is not it necessary to use numpy for faster performance?

Comment: sorry there was writing mistake in my question CORRECT ONE is: index = reference_array == unique  Does your code still works?

Comment: this was a obvious mistake, I even don't need unique for my solution.

Comment: reading large lists in the memory melts down computer, this code must be changed so that the results are written to disk once computed.

Comment: how large are your arrays, and how many unique values are there?

Comment: So i'm correct if your `given_array` as a size of 150GB and reference_array of more than 1TB? If you get these arrays into memory, you should have no problem with memory with the second example, the `unique`-table uses only a few hundred megabytes. Btw, you could only read portions of the arrays into memory.

Comment: Nope, I tried with the second array and yes PC does not working. I'm sorry the size of both arrays are not so large, they are 40000, 40000.

Comment: Correction: Both array have the size of 40000, 40000. The unique value of reference array are 1 to 1600000. The given array is in Byte (0 to 255)

Comment: THere is no problem until reading out both the two arrays, but later on computing the mean of unique indices, the computer really hangs out. IS not it possible to write the results one by one immediately after computing into the disk?

Comment: With your sizes i've done a timing test and it says, it needs less than two hours. The advantage of my algorithm is, that it needs only **one** run through the data, to get all mean values, and not up to 1600000 runs.

Comment: whoops, I used zip rather than izip before, and the PC hanged out. Now corrected and running smoothly. Let's see the result. I have accepted your answer, and would be happy if you could explain little bit about your code, the second one.

Comment: Yes, I checked the results, and it works correctly. Would e grateful if you explain how it works.

Comment: upvoted for the advancement of the code. but it's very difficult to be understood by the newbie, could you please elaborate it more: especially, add, lambda

Comment: I got RuntimeWarning: add = lambda (a,b), c: (a+c, b+1) overflow encountered in long_scalars. Is it important?

Comment: @simen: oh, yes, that's bad. You're using `numpy.int`s which can overflow. I've now converted the values to float to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the whole thing to work in numpy using `unique` and `bincount`. Since numpy's `unique` uses sorting, it is going to have linearithmic complexity, but it typically beats pure Python code using dictionaries, despite the linear complexity.

If you are using numpy 1.9 or newer:

```
>>> unq, inv, cnts = np.unique(reference_array, return_inverse=True,
...                            return_counts=True)
>>> means = np.bincount(inv, weights=given_array.ravel()) / cnts

>>> unq
array([ 2,  4,  8,  9, 15])
>>> means
array([  2.83333333,   4.        ,   7.8       ,   7.        ,  15.        ])
```

With older numpy's it would be marginally slower, but you would do something like:

```
>>> unq, inv = np.unique(reference_array, return_inverse=True)
>>> cnts = np.bincount(inv)
>>> means = np.bincount(inv, weights=given_array.ravel()) / cnts
```

---

**EDIT**

For more elaborate operations you will need to replicate the guts of `np.unique`. First, sort both flattened arrays based on the contents of `reference_array`:

```
>>> sort_idx = np.argsort(reference_array, axis=None)
>>> given_sort = given_array.ravel()[sort_idx]
>>> ref_sort = reference_array.ravel()[sort_idx]
```

Then count the number of items in each group:

```
>>> first_mask = np.concatenate(([True], ref_sort[:-1] != ref_sort[1:]))
>>> first_idx, = np.nonzero(first_mask)
>>> cnts = np.diff(np.concatenate((first_idx, [ref_sort.size])))
>>> cnts
array([6, 1, 5, 1, 1])
>>> unq = ref_sort[first_mask]
>>> unq
array([ 2,  4,  8,  9, 15])
```

Finally, compute your group calculation, using ufuncs and their `reduceat` method, e.g. for the group `max`:

```
>>> np.maximum.reduceat(given_sort, first_idx)
array([ 5,  4, 11,  7, 15])
```

Comment: Superb, this is what I was exactly looking for. I would be more happy if you provide more general way of doing it so that I could use it not only for mean but also for standard deviation, I want to use np.mean, np.stdev. Is it possible with out compromising most of the performance?

Comment: I am using numpy 1.9.

Comment: It is not a very numerically stable approach, but you can compute the standard deviation from the sum of the values in each group, `sx = np.bincount(inv, weights=given_array.ravel())` and the sum of their squares, `sx2 = np.bincount(inv, weights=given_array.ravel()**2)`, see e.g. [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477857/mean-values-depending-on-binning-with-respect-to-second-variable/15478137#15478137) for details.

Comment: I am looking for more general way so that I could use np.max() as well